# External linkage prefered over internal linkage in c++11

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In [clause C.2.6 Clause 14: templates point 3 14.6.4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/diff.cpp03.temp)

> Change: Allow dependent calls of functions with internal linkage
>
> Rationale: Overly constrained, simplify overload resolution rules.
>
> Effect on original feature: A valid C++ 2003 program could get a different result than this International
> Standard.

I understood from clause that functions with internal linkage are preferred over functions having external linkage. But here function always result A even f(A) is mentioned as extern. Any example that can justify this clause?

```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> struct B { }; 
> struct A : B { };  
> extern void f(A); 
> template<typename T> void g(T t) { f(t); }
>  void f(A) { cout<<"A"<<endl;}
>   void f(B) { cout<<"B"<<endl;}
>  int main() { A a; g(a); }
```

Comment: Note both functions `f` have external linkage, by default.

Comment: Can you add a link to the actual diff from Annex C? Section numbers have changed over time, and will continue to change, so it's preferable to have a link to whichever draft you're referring to.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/diff.cpp03.temp

Comment: @aschepler yes, both are external linkage bydeafault, even if i make f(B) as static, it'll print A only.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that functions with internal linkage are preferred. It's that the older 2003 Standard didn't allow them at all, but in the 2011 Standard and later, they're allowed and treated as equals.

C++03 [temp.dep.candidate], emphasis mine:

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, if the function name is an *unqualified-id* but not a *template-id*, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), only function declarations **with external linkage** from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations **with external linkage** found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

C++11 [temp.dep.candidate]:

> For a function call where the *postfix-expression* is a dependent name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in
>   either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

So this sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct B {};
struct A : B {};
static void f(A) { std::cout << "A\n"; }
void f(B) { std::cout << "B\n"; } // extern
template<typename T> void g(T t) { f(t); }
int main() { A a; g(a); }
```

should print "B" in C++03, or "A" in C++11 and later. Though I can't find any compiler versions which actually obey the older C++03 rule, trying some actual pre-2011 versions and some newer versions with `-std=c++03`.

Comment: Tried with both compiler   -std=gnu++11  and  -std=gnu++03, output is A in both cases. @aschelper

Comment: Yes, I think that's incorrect for '03, but it seems few compilers actually obeyed that rule in the first place, so the Standard change was actually just matching what implementations already did.